# SQLite update query optimisation

Tags: android, performance, android-sqlite

Part of my functionality requires updating a value in every row (only happens rarely, when a user selects a certain setting).

Trouble is, the query takes a good few minutes to perform (at best), and there's only 269 test records. Is there any way this could be optimized?

```
    String allRecords = "SELECT id, weight FROM Workout_Entry";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(allRecords, null);

    int rows = cursor.getCount();

    int id;
    double weight;

    try
    {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    id = cursor.getInt(0);
                    weight = cursor.getInt(1) / 2.2;

                    String strFilter = "id = " + id;
                    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                    args.put("weight", weight);

                    db.update("Workout_Entry", args, strFilter, null);

                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    (db).close();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've realised my error. I had a `do while` loop for every record, and inside of that was a `for loop` which looped through `x` many times, where `x` was the amount of existing records.

So it was going through `O(n)²` times instead of `O(n)`.

Thanks to those who replied! I found both of your comments useful.

Answer (score 2):

Just push the work to the database engine instead of pulling the data out one row at a time and firing up a new update query each time. Replace your code with something like:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE Workout_Entry SET weight=weight/2.2");
```

Also, since this seems to be some kind of metric/imperial unit conversion, consider keeping the data in just one format in the database and convert/format to the appropriate unit for display purposes.

Comment: Actually i agree this is the more precise solution for the specific problem +1

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use transactions - you can see example of how you use that in this [presentation of mine](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wTc3UjuktHCgqEJijyg6JRcvX-VizYMTt33smf--yXA/edit?usp=drive_web).

Also showing the impact of not using the transaction.